# Loop Inside node.js module

Tags: node.js

Here is my module.

```
module.exports = function (requestUser) {  

  let content = `

    <div id="cpl">
      <table id="currentpatientslists">
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="rp">
      <h1>Requested Patients</h1>
    </div>
    <hr>    
    <div id="note" >Currently no patients</div>
    <div id="rpl">
    <table id="requestedpatientslists">    
    <tr>
    <td width="30%"></td>
    <td width="30%" class="right"><button>Accept</button></td>
    <td width="30%" class="left"><button>Reject</button></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>`;

  return render(content);
}
```

In the requestedpatientslists table , I want to loop the data  in the table row coming from requestUser which is an array. I want to loop it until requestUser.length. How can I do that?

Comment: Consider using a templating library to generate a function that can be used to produce the desired document.  Although backticks can be used to interpolate simple values into a string, trying to construct complex strings this way will result in unmaintainable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to loop over the users and create the rows for them first

```
module.exports = function(requestUser) {
  // I'm guessing that the user has normal properties like name, etc?
  const tableRows = requestUser.map(
    user => `
    <tr>
      <td width="30%">${user.name}</td>
      <td width="30%" class="right"><button>Accept</button></td>
      <td width="30%" class="left"><button>Reject</button></td>
    </tr>
  `,
  );
  const content = `

    <div id="cpl">
      <table id="currentpatientslists">
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="rp">
      <h1>Requested Patients</h1>
    </div>
    <hr>    
    <div id="note" >Currently no patients</div>
    <div id="rpl">
    <table id="requestedpatientslists">    
    ${tableRows.join('\n')}
    </table>
    </div>`;

  return render(content);
};
```

Comment: I think OP is doing a crazy job so that make code like this!

Comment: I've definitely seen much worse

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I'm new in this. I'm in the learning phase.